# Canvas Renderer in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have recently started working on webgl with Three.js with the following tutorial ,

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-sphere-with-three-js/

When i use  THREE.WebGLRenderer() to draw a sphere, everything works fine but if i use THREE.CanvasRenderer() i get a pattern of intersecting  line's on my sphere. Is it possible to make those lines invisible?

Can anyone explain me the diffrence between them?

in the following code 150 is the radius but what does 100,100 mean?
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(150, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());

Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem is solved. Need to set overdraw property to true in the mesh material.

Comment: You should explain your solution in an answer and mark it as solved.